# Django - getting a syntax error in a class generic views

Tags: python, django, view, syntax

Right now I`m learning django and going through documentation. And when I try to use generic views it gives me an exeption:

```
  File "/home/jeffr/Рабочий стол/codetry/mysite1/polls/views.py", line 8
     def IndexView(generic.ListView):
                          ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**This is my views.py:**

```
    from django.views import generic

    from .models import Choice, Question

    def IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'polls/index.html'
         contest_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions"""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    def DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Question
        template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
```

The full traceback paste can be found here: http://dpaste.com/3QMN3A0

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: You define a *function, you should use `class IndexView(...)` instead of `def IndexView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **`def`** keyword means you are implementing a *function*. But here you are not specifying a function, but a *class*. You define a class with the **`class`** keyword, like:

```
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
     contest_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions"""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
```

This raises an error since functions can take parameters, but the parameter names, can not contain dots.

You also forgot to use a `def` to define the `get_queryset` method.